# Javascript string comparison/sorting without using < or >

Tags: javascript

So I need to sort an array of objects in Javascript by the "name" property. I am able to do so using the following:

```
fileArray.sort(function(a, b) {
    var nameA = a.name.toLowerCase();
    var nameB = b.name.toLowerCase();
    if (nameA < nameB) {return -1;}
    else {return 1;}
});
```

This works quite nicely, except my code must pass through a very strict parser that throws an error when it sees a '<' or '>' in the code that isn't attached to HTML. I tried subbing "$lt;", which passes the parser, but then causes a Javascript error once the page gets published and hits the browser. Is there any way to execute this sort in a way that will pass the parser?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The answer is to get a parser than isn't a piece of crap.

Comment: Did you do `$lt;` or `&lt;`? Is this within a <script> tag in an HTML file?

Comment: I'd trade a few of my toes for a new parser, but I'm nowhere near important enough to make that call.

Comment: Can you just move the JavaScript code to a separate `.js` file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`localeCompare()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare).

```
fileArray.sort(function(a, b) {
    var nameA = a.name.toLowerCase();
    var nameB = b.name.toLowerCase();
    return nameA.localeCompare(nameB);
});
```

Comment: @Eric - Warning: per MDN, the options for `localeCompare()` are not supported by Safari so this wouldn't do a case insensitive sort on Safari.

Comment: @jfriend00 You're absolutely right, thanks for pointing that out. Answer has been updated.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `localeCompare()` method on the string.  It compares the two strings and gives you back the right kind of return value for the sort function.

```
fileArray.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.name.toLowerCase().localeCompare(b.name.toLowerCase());
});
```

[MDN reference for localeCompare](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare)

There are also a number of options on the `localeCompare()` method that help you control how it behaves if you want to define behavior for numbers, special characters, etc... though the options are not necessarily supported in all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

While I upvoted and couldn't agree more with the suggestion of a new parser, if that for some reason is not an option, I think you will find the `String` object's [`.localeCompare()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare)function will let you avoid `>` and `<`, as it performs a comparison and returns `-1`, `0`, or `1` depending on the relationship, which you could then code up with just equality tests against the result.

Actually, reading the doc suggest that `localeCompare()` is not guaranteed to return (e.g.) -1, it could '-2, or -1, or some other negative value' to quote from the doc.

If it were guaranteed to return +/-1 you could more or less just return its result. However, you would in this case want to test if the `result` of `localeCompare()` is equal to zero, and then see if `result` is equal to `Math.abs(result)` to check for a positive or negative result.